# Google Crawler. Searches the 100 first google results for some term

Tags: php, object-oriented

I wrote a simple Google Crawler in PHP, and my GoogleProxy interface does not seem to follow the Single Responsibility Principle.

Here's my Interface code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Interface that represents an online proxy service.
 * Every class that implement it must know how to return the apropriate ResponseInterface to an url based on what
 * the proxy service needs, and must know how to parse an url used within its pages.
 *
 * @package CViniciussDias\GoogleCrawler\Proxy
 * @author Vinicius Dias
 */
interface GoogleProxy
{
    /**
     * Gets the ResponseInterface for the informed URL based on all the information that
     * the proxy service needs
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function getHttpResponse(string $url): ResponseInterface;

    /**
     * Parses an URL based on how they are encoded in the proxy service
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    public function parseUrl(string $url): string;
}
```

And one of its implementations:

```
<?php
namespace CViniciusSDias\GoogleCrawler\Proxy;

use CViniciusSDias\GoogleCrawler\Exception\InvalidResultException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

/**
 * Class that represents the absense of a proxy service, making the direct request to the url
 * and returning its response
 *
 * @package CViniciussDias\GoogleCrawler\Proxy
 * @author Vinicius Dias
 */
class NoProxy implements GoogleProxy
{
    public function getHttpResponse(string $url): ResponseInterface
    {
        return (new Client())->request('GET', $url);
    }

    public function parseUrl(string $url): string
    {
        // Separates the url parts
        $link = parse_url($url);
        // Parses the parameters of the url query
        parse_str($link['query'], $link);

        $url = filter_var($link['q'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
        // If this is not a valid URL, so the result is (probably) an image, news or video suggestion
        if (!$url) {
            throw new InvalidResultException();
        }

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Here's the full code if needed (I would enjoy some pull requests too):
https://github.com/CViniciusSDias/google-crawler

Should I split the two tasks it performs into 2 separate classes? Several other Proxies will be implemented in a near future. Wouldn't it make the number of classes increase more than necessary?

Comment: This code has a lot of comments. Made it a little hard to read for me. I read somewhere that if you choose good class and method and variable names, you shouldn't really need any comments.

Comment: The comments are for generating documentation with phpdoc or sami, @AdmiralAdama .

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Usually when naming an interface, you want to give some hint as to what actions that interface describes.  Here I don't quite understand what implementing `GoogleProxy` should be able to do for the implementing class.  What do getting a response and parsing a URL have to do with a proxy? What do these methods have to do with Google specifically? Would this interface better be named as `HttpClient` or something like that which indicates that these are the methods that need to be implemented by a class to enable the request/response aspects of crawling?
- You might consider adding `@throws` in your interface documentation for `parseUrl()`.  Not that this really does anything, but perhaps at least it can drive code consistency in having implementing classes throw appropriate exceptions and might help when working in an IDE.
- In your `getHttpResponse()` implementation, you are doing nothing to either handle underlying exceptions that can be thrown by the Guzzle Client or indicate that the function might throw (why no doc blocks in implementing class?).
- You should namespace your interface file.
- In your `parseUrl()`, I think it is problematic that you are parsing the query string into the same array that you put your `parse_url()` results into.  Why not just create a new array here to eliminate confusion over what your intent is and to eliminate any possibility of overwriting date in `$link()` (if you ever wanted to do anything else with that data.
- Should you really throw an exception if the URL value in the query string is not valid? I would think that this could be an expected occurrence that you might need to handle as you have no control over this input. Does this really represent an unexpected state in your application as is often the intended use for throwing exceptions?
- Should you add some validation for the parametric input to both of these functions (i.e. non-zero length string, properly formed URL). In your `getHttpResponse()` implementation you can get as far as attempting to make a (relatively expensive) call on a remote host even if you have an empty string or invalid URL passed to the method.  I generally think it good practice to enforce some basic level of validation on parameters passed to public methods, perhaps throwing `InvalidArgumentException` or similar before getting into method logic such that you are failing fast and failing loudly when bad input is passed.
- From looking at your wider library on Github, it seems as if you are trying to work with dependency injection. If you want to be consistent in this approach, I would think your implementing classes would need to take on dependencies such as the Guzzle client in their constructors, as opposed to within the methods that are implementing the interface.
- With the above thought in mind, I am actually not sure that what you have right now is even best modeled as an interface vs. class inheritance since all the proxy classes you currently have implemented don't really do much outside of implement these two methods.

Comment: Thank you vary much for all the tips. Just answering your questions:
"What do getting a response and parsing a URL have to do with a proxy? What do these methods have to do with Google specifically?"
As explained in the project README.md, Google blocks you after several requests. This interface makes it possible to use som online proxy services. The getHttpResponse gives the Google page using the proxy and the parseUrl parses the url that is encoded by the proxy service.

Comment: About the 4 tip: My interface is namespaced. This part just got out of my "copy - paste". Sorry.
:-)

Comment: I am not receiving Guzzle as parameter injected on constructor on my GoogleProxy implementing classes because one of their jobs is specificly create the Guzzle client with the necessary parameters that the proxy service requires.

Comment: I sure will add some more validations to my classes and the before mentioned @throws tags. I was thinking about GoogleProxyHandler for my interface name. What do you think of that? HttpClient is too generic. The interface is for Google specific tasks.

Comment: I throw an exception on parseUrl() because if the url parsed is not valid, than it is not a valid Google Result and should not be inserted on the ResultList. What would be a better aproach?

Comment: I did not quite get the last observation you made. Are you suggesting turn the GoogleProxy interface into an abstract class?

Comment: Again, thank you very much and sorry for all these comments. If this is not the right way to communicate, please let me know. I'm new in here.

Comment: @ViniciusDias With regards to naming, I have better idea on what you are getting at now.  I still don't know what it would spepcifically have to do with Google at the interface level.  Could you not technically use the proxies to point at other non-Google endpoints?  Perhaps a concrete implementation that is specifically configured to work with Google might have "Google" in it's naming.  With regards to inheritance vs. interface, I was just questioning whether an interface was really appropriate. Perhaps abstract base class might make more sense.

Comment: the component is specific for google crawling. It doesn't make sense to use any part of it to something other than searching on Google. About the abstract class... Would it be an Abstract class with 2 abstract methods? Why would it make more sense than an interface? Thank you one more time! :-)